# Kotlin Coroutines suspend fun + retrofit throws "No Retrofit annotation found" error

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

I'm trying to use retrofit's coroutine support in 2.5.1-SNAPSHOT but I keep getting a strange exception.

My retrofit service class has:

```
@GET("weather")
suspend fun getForecast(@Query("q") query: String, @Query("num_of_days") numDays: String = "1",
                @Query("format") format : String = "json", @Query("key") apiKey: String = API_KEY)
        : Weather
```

And when I try to call it I get:

```
2019-05-18 13:57:01.507 27422-27477/com.my.app  E/MainPresenter$onResume$$inlined$CoroutineExceptionHandler: Something went wrong: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #5)
    for method WeatherService.getForecast
```

Which seems odd, since the error is with parameter #5, but there are only 4 parameters.  Anyone seen this before?

Also note, this is for a debug build with

```
minifyEnabled false
```

So I doubt it's proguard...

Comment: I don't have a solution, but the problem is because the Kotlin compiler changes your method to take an extra argument, used for the coroutine continuation.

Comment: I already solved it, and posted the solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you need the SNAPSHOT version of the converter factory as well.

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.5.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: and where did you get that snapshot version?

Comment: check out this guide I wrote https://medium.com/@daptronic/migrate-from-rxjava-to-kotlin-coroutines-a-step-by-step-guide-488d039744cc

You have to add the snapshot repo to your project build.gradle.  It's all in there ^^^

Comment: Retrofit 2.6.0 is now out ( https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md ), which contains suspend support.  If you're still using the snapshot, you can just upgrade to the latest version

Answer (score 3):

You need update retrofit, version > 2'6