# No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #6), but I only have 5 parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-api-3, retrofit, dagger

I'm using dagger to inject retrofit for google directions api. The error seems to suggest I have 1 more parameter than I think I should have.

If I add another parameter in the interface, I will get error "No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #7)" instead.

Edit: see Nicholas' comment. I found another issue afterwards, that due to the suspend function, in the interface GoogleMapServices, the Call<> wrappers should be removed or changed per:
[Retrofit 2.0 + GSON Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749752/retrofit-2-0-gson-unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-interface)

Dagger module

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {

//  @Provides
//  @Singleton
//  fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
//    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
//      .addInterceptor(RequestInterceptor())
//      .build()
//  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideRetrofit(@NonNull okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
      //.client(okHttpClient) removed to narrow down the issues
      .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com")
      .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
      //.addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
      .build()
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideGoogleMapsService(@NonNull retrofit: Retrofit): GoogleMapsService {
    return retrofit.create(GoogleMapsService::class.java)
  }
}
```

Google Maps Directions interface

```
interface GoogleMapsService {
    @GET("maps/api/directions/json")
    suspend fun fetchDirection(
        @Query("origin") origin: String,
        @Query("destination") destination: String,
        @Query("mode") travelMode: String,
        @Query("arrival_time") arrivalTime: String
        @Query("key") apiKey: String
    ): Call<DirectionResponses>
```

ViewModel

```
class detailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MyRepository,
    private val service: GoogleMapsService
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    fun test() {
        uiScope.launch {
            suspendCall()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun suspendCall() {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            direction.value = service.fetchDirection("aaa","bbb", "ccc","1600000000", "apikey").toString()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Error Message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.example, PID: 21142
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #6)
        for method GoogleMapsService.fetchDirection
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:52)
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:42)
        at retrofit2.Utils.parameterError(Utils.java:61)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:311)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:182)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:65)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:25)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:168)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy2.fetchDirection(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.example.<...>.DetailViewModel$suspendCall$2.invokeSuspend(DetailViewModel.kt:72)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
```

Comment: Actually there's a 6th parameter, the coroutine `Continuation<T>`, because you have a suspending function. What's the problem with that, I don't know.

Comment: What's your retrofit version? I just saw this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201771/kotlin-coroutines-suspend-fun-retrofit-throws-no-retrofit-annotation-found-e

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, that is exactly the problem, I was still using 2.5.0 for some reason.